# Can't connect mysql db under my domain

Tags: mysql, node.js, hostmonster

I host my domain on hostmonster.com, I created a new mysql user named admin@localhost and database test, its working fine in my local, but when I immigrate into my domain, some error happened: Access denied for user 'admin'@'host165.hostmonster.com'. I think because I don't have this 'admin'@'host165.hostmonster.com' user, I want to know how to create such user by CPanel or shell cmd

Comment: Does the hosting plan you have allow access to MySQL? cPanel should have a utility to create new databases and users (different from MyPHPAdmin)

Comment: I can create user by cPanel, but its always like somename@localhost, I can't change the @localhost to @% or @%.hostmonster.com

Comment: Edit your question and show the code that is generating the error (hide user id/password). I suspect you're using a user id that is for the server instead of passing the correct credentials in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link from hostmoster on how to create database and user. Please follow the link. The hostname "localhost" should be right.
[HostMonster Create Database User](https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/6)